# Wildcards in exclude-filelist for duplicity

Tags: backup, rsync, wildcards, duplicity, rdiff-backup

I am trying to exclude a "bulk" folder in each home directory from the backup. For this purpose, I have a line

```
- /data/home/*/bulk
```

in my exclude-filelist file.

However, this doesn't seem to be recognised:

```
Warning: file specification '/data/home/*/bulk' in filelist exclude-list-test.txt
doesn't start with correct prefix /data/home/kay/bulk.  Ignoring.
```

Is there a way?

BTW: is the format in general compatible with rsync's exclude-from? I have a working exclude list for that, where this wildcard expression works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the problem lies on an improper passing of the path with wildcard character by the duplicity to the rsync. Look at the example below. This is the real example of passing excludes to the rsync by an environment variable within a script:

EXCLUDES="--exclude=/etc/blkid.tab --exclude=/root/dir1 --exclude='*.sql'"

Notice that quotation marks '' are used to separate the entry containing asterisk to prevent a shell from expanding this wildcard character. Try to use quotation marks within the exclude-list-test.txt file.

Comment: I tried to use  
    - '/data/home/**/bulk'  
Still gives me "Warning: file specification ''/data/home/**/bulk'' in filelist exclude-list-test.txt
doesn't start with correct prefix /data/home/kay/bulk.  Ignoring."  
I tried --exclude-globbing-filelist now with my original file. This does work in general, but results in an error when one of the lines is outside the source path.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason line breaks with two spaces didn't seem to work.

Comment: If your path has the pattern as above you should use --exclude-globbing-filelist and:

Comment: If your path has the pattern as above you should use --exclude-globbing-filelist and /data/home/*/bulk inside an excludes file. Double asterisk matches subfolders and it's not your goal in this case I guess. I don't know if you're using any includes also -- it could take precedence and change exclude acting as well. See 'File Selction' chapter of the duplicity manual: http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html